# static website hosted in s3: pages return 404 after refresh

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-router-dom

With this bucket policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mypage.com/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am deploying a website that is build by reactJS v16+ (react-router-dom v5), and when I open the url, it works perfectly, e.g. from mypage.com, the  that goes to /list works fine. Url is loaded as mypage.com/list and the page content is displayed.

However on any child page that is not homepage, for example mypage.com/list, once I refresh the page with browser, it returns S3's 404:

```
404 Not Found

    Code: NoSuchKey
    Message: The specified key does not exist.
    Key: list
```

I don't even know how to debug this... any idea?

Comment: Have you tried adding `index.html`(or your root html file) as error document(on `Error Pages` creating a custom error message and setting response code to 200). This is one of the easiest hack to get this working.

Comment: @Panther that indeed works! I am very curious to what happened and why this hack would work though, do you mind putting this as an answer and I would gladly accept it.

Comment: Is there an actual file called `list` in the root of your bucket, or when users go to `mypage.com/list` are you wanting them to actually see the `index.html` file in the `/list` directory?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein no /list is not a real html page. It's a react web app so /listing is managed by the JS in the index.html page.

Comment: Do you have `index.html` as the `index` document? What happens if you go to `mypage.com/list/` (with the final slash) but without the Error Page hack?

Comment: The web works fine, but the console error 404 not found still there, is there any way to fix it also?

Comment: set response code to 200 via CloudFront. see answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59351656/556649

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As @Panther mentioned in the comment, the right way to go is to add an error fallback to index.html in the S3 bucket's static web hosting configuration.

The reason of this is when a URL is hit (either by manual input in the browser or a refresh), it sends a request to /list to the S3's root server (the one managed by AWS) before it hits our bucket. That S3 server have no idea if this is a reactjs app or not, so it goes into the bucket to look for the /list in the root of my bucket, which doesn't exist, so it returns the 404 error.

However by adding the error fallback, now when it gets 404, it redirects the request to index.html, where the react app defined and loaded into. In this case, the /list will go through the normal flow to reach the right router that handles page rendering, problem solved.

Comment: I have index.html in both spots and it redirects but the 404 still shows up in the console.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @StephenPhillips so you mean the page eventually shows up correctly, but the original 404 still shows up in console?

Comment: yep that is exactly what is happening.  Is that what is supposed to happen?

Comment: @StephenPhillips no I don't think it is normal, as I have not run into this once I fixed my 404 redirection problem.

Comment: @StephenPhillips maybe worth asking your own question.

Comment: @jamesdeath123, thanks for the explanation, Panther's suggestion works for me too

Answer (score 10):

So, I had the same experience today, and the answer by @jamesdeath123 helped me too know the cause. In my case I am using [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html), so I was finding a way to generate the **error.html** to be used in s3 bucket. I realized though, that all I need to do is to set the `error` page to **index.html** as well.