# Is it possible to customise HTTP status code when error document is returned in S3 static website hosting

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-status-code-404, amazon-cloudfront

I am using S3 static website hosting to deploy code. I want to send 200 status code when error document is served. currently, it is sending 404 status code. Is it possible to customize the status code.

[image: I can't see any option here to set HTTP status code]

I can't see any option here to set HTTP status code.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: 200 status is not for error document why you want it??

Comment: Yes I know. I have a special case :d. My index.html file is getting served as error document. You can read first answer from this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56345645/static-website-hosted-in-s3-pages-return-404-after-refresh to get more idea why index.html is getting served as error document

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do by following step :

1. Open `CloudFront` and select relevant `CloudFront`
2. Go to Error Page tab
3. Create custom page error handling as it showing images below

[image]

[image]

Comment: This isn't ideal, since it will catch 400's and 403's from all origins (for example, api and static endpoints). You might not want to silently convert error codes from api endpoints.

Comment: Its only catch application URL status.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean :S